# Compiling generating the following error: "error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints Todo,TodoCouchDB"

Tags: java, couchdb

I'm trying to learn Java by writing a little todo list console app that can save todos to either the filesystem or to CouchDB. Unfortunately, I'm hitting a compiler issue reading todos from CouchDB (using the [LightCouch](http://www.lightcouch.org/) library) and have absolutely no idea how to move forward.

I have the following classes:

- `Todo`, `TodoFilesystem`, `TodoCouchDB`
- `Listx`, `ListFilesystem`, `ListCouchDB`

Here's the content of `ListCouchDB`:

```
public class ListCouchDB extends Listx {
    public void load() {
        CouchDbClient dbClient = new CouchDbClient();
        list = dbClient.view("_all_docs").includeDocs(true).query(TodoCouchDB.class);
    }
}
```

The `list` variable is an instance variable defined on the superclass:

```
public class Listx {
    public List<Todo> list = new ArrayList<Todo>();

    ...
}
```

Compiling this code throws the following compiler error:

```
ListCouchDB.java:12: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints Todo,TodoCouchDB
        list = dbClient.view("_all_docs").includeDocs(true).query(TodoCouchDB.class);
                                                                 ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>query(Class<T>)
1 error
```

When I change `query(TodoCouchDB.class)` to `query(Todo.class)` in the `ListCouchDB` class it actually compiles and correctly populates my list; however, the list contains an array of `Todo` items and therefore if I try to call any methods on an item in the list it incorrectly calls the methods on the `Todo` superclass and not the `TodoCouchDB` subclass.

Apologies if there is insufficient info. here, but appreciate any input anyone is able to offer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use generic types.

Define your Listx using generics

```
public class Listx<T extends Todo> {
 public List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
 ...
}
```

Define ListCouchDB as an extension of `Listx<TodoCouchDB>`

```
public class ListCouchDB extends Listx<TodoCouchDB> {
    public void load() {
        CouchDbClient dbClient = new CouchDbClient();
        list = dbClient.view("_all_docs").includeDocs(true).query(TodoCouchDB.class);
    }
}
```

Now, your `list` property is a list of TodoCouchDB instances